# javascript small fade in fade out library that using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've try one by one on microjs, but they are not complete. I don't use jQuery because i just want to do simple animation like `fadeIn() fadeOut() with stop()` function using `requestAnimationFrame`.

`nwtjs, xuijs, morpheus, tweenJS, vivi, shifty and other small JS anim. libs at microjs` seem not complete. For example, `morpheus+ender`, they have `fadeIn() & out` but they do different than jQuery.

jQuery fadeOut: reduce opacity then display none. jQuery fadeIn: display it then increase opacity to the original. But morpheus+ender do different thing, and i dont know, whether they have handy `stop()` function or not.

There is `gsap, tweenJS,` but... no

For now, i still use custom build of jQuery minified Filesize: **55.88 Kb** / Gzip: 19.28 Kb just for animating elements and doing css. That is not efficient, plus jQuery doesn't use `requestAnimationFrame`

So, what is another animation library that using requestAnimationFrame with methods like `fadeIn, fadeOut, stop` ? Or, how to build our own functions?

Comment: Would you accept a code example of how to perform these in modern browsers? Is CSS transitions an option?

Comment: @alex : if you want to show your own functions, please show me, it would be very helpful. i also use trick by add/remove css class with callback. but i feel not beauty

Comment: If I remember I will write some tonight.